# final variable might not have initialized

Tags: java, android

I have code like this within a method:

```
final TouchableSpan touchableSpan = new TouchableSpan() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        this.setPressed(true);

        String extravar = touchableSpan.getMyVar();
    }
```

On this line `String extravar = touchableSpan.getMyVar();` I get a warning that variable `touchableSpan` might have not been initialized. Why is there?

This warning appeared when I added `final` modifier. Before I had `variable is access from inner class, needs to be declared final`.

Comment: Consider if `TouchableSpan` has a constructor `TouchableSpan() {this.onClick(null);}` or similar.

Comment: This has definitely some "bad smell". If your method `onClick()` really needs to access an element **outside** of the TouchableSpan class; then you should provide that "outside element" via a constructor for example. You code is extremely coupling the part that creates a new TouchableSpan object ... with the code of that class. Don't do that!

Comment: @Jägermeister, yeah, I'll use `this.getMyVar()` as `@Tagir` suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first create an anonymous class and then assign it to the final variable. Thus your `onClick` method theoretically might be called before final variable initialization. Why not just using `this.getMyVar()`?